# How to Write Javascript Alert from Laravel Controller?

Tags: javascript, laravel

here, this code inside laravel controller

this code define from controller and use to javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello!");</script>
```

it will occure  error

Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: more explanation. more code. a real question. I think this will be closed soon

Comment: Looks like you're just testing how Laravel and JS work. Put this code into the Blade view you're executing. If you've just installed Laravel, put this to `resources/view/welcome.blade.php`

Comment: simple this javascript alert in laravel controller
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello!");</script>';

Comment: To print HTML on a blade template simply put inside here {!! your_html  !!}

Comment: `simple this javascript alert in laravel controller` - Laravel is `PHP` and executed on the server side. This is part of a template

Comment: @ Alexey Mezenin not in blade but in controller

Comment: A good understanding of what controllers are for would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try:**

```
echo "<script>";
echo "alert('hello');";
echo "</script>";
```

**Or try this:**

```
return redirect()->back()->with('alert','hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@push('stylesheets')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom/css/required/by/child">
@endpush

@push('scripts')
    <script src="custom/js/required/by/child"></script>
@endpush
```